# Collecting data from txt using execl

Tags: c, parallel-processing, fork

I have a project in which I have to collect some records from a .txt and sort them using exec*(). When I call execl I sort some of them ( the first 10 records for example ) and at the same time (because I have used fork() before execl) I sort some records using another execl. But the problem is that the records of the second execl are the same with those of the first one. Does anyone know a way to handle the records in order to sort different records at each execl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for how to do parallel sorting using mutiple processes?

Comment: what exactly are you sorting ??  if you sort comparing between records  using 2 process . you should again sort the sorted records so that you get final result

Comment: Actually I use a binary tree , where each child is created by fork(). When I reach leaves i call again fork() and then execl. Then I can use through execl a program of quick sort (left leaves) and one of shell sort (right leaves). So the number of sorts is not static. And yes i sort between records (for example each record is just a number)

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you need to have each process work on only part of the file. This means you need to communicate to each process which part of the file they need to work on. There are different options for accomplishing this, but one is to have each process skip over the lines that should not be processed before calling `exec()`. Alternatively, set up different pipes to each process, and a master process feeds the input into each worker process. There are several other possibilities.

Comment: I have to use pipes to send the results back to the root of the tree. It's my first project in OS so i don't know if a can use pipes to pass results from a program to another (though execl). Is that what you are writing above?

Comment: Since classical pipes are unidirectional, you would need a pair of pipes to allow for bidirectional communication.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i will try it and I wil tell.

Comment: I didn't manage to do it with the way you suggest. I am making it with txts that i create and remove . Thanks anyway. First time in stack overflow and super fast response. That's nice!